# BigQuery + PlayStore +Apps History data

Tags: google-bigquery

we are working on to integrate our apps data to BigQuery. as a part of that we are using BigQuery Transfer service to bring in the apps store data.
I think the way the scheduled transfer works is, from the day we set up it would begin to bring in any new incremental data from there on which works for future data set.

we also have existing data that we want to use along with the latest+future data. when i use the "schedule backfill" option here i can go and bring in any previous data except that when i use the existing data set it seems to wipe off the current dataset.

Also at a time you can only schedule for 6 months of data.. we can create new dataset and try custom merge etc.. but i was wondering are there any other way how i can keep the previous and future data in single data set without writing any custom code/configs.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, when a transfer is configured, the data will be populated within BigQuery from the day it is configured.

Backfills don't wipe off the current dataset; however, please note that if you include a date in a backfill that already has data within BigQuery, the data of that day will be overwritten.

Although some services have no data retention limit like [Google Play](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/play-transfer#supported_reports), the BigQuery Data Transfer Service has limits on how many days can be requested in a [single backfill](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/working-with-transfers#backfilling), in other words, Google Play doesn't have a limit to provide backfill, but on the BigQuery side, you will need to schedule backfills in chunks of 180 days.

If the data transfer service you are using has a data retention limit, it will be necessary to create a separate ETL process to load the data beyond that limit; however, as per my understanding you are trying to use the [Play Transfer](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/play-transfer) and it has no known limit for backfills, you only need to schedule a backfill with a range of 180 days, and when it is completed, schedule a new one for the next 180 days.